# Wait for data to get loaded in model before accessing them in ViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, viewcontroller

I'm struggling with letting my ViewVontroller know when all the data are loaded successfully. My ViewController has a list of Stop objects, all these objects have a list of Bus objects. In each Stop I call an API and populate the list of Bus objects. I got completion blocks for knowing when the job is done, in each Stop object. However, when I want to use them in my ViewController I'm am pretty much lost how to do it. I want to make sure that every single Stop object has a complete list of Busses, before I use them. The solution at the moment is to wait for 2 seconds and then use them, not a preferable solution, but it gives me some data to work with. Any suggestions? I guess I can't call a method from my ViewController in my model, since this would break MVC-pattern, right?

```
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {

var nearbyStops = [Stop]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    animateLogoEntry()

    GPSUtil.sharedInstance.startGPS()

    stopsNearby(initialLocation, maxRadius: 1000, maxNumber: 5)

}

// MARK: - API work

/**
 Assigns the array of Stops to the nearby stops
*/
func stopsNearby(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, maxRadius: Int, maxNumber: Int) {
    APIHelper.sharedInstance.getStopsNearby(location, maxRadius: maxRadius, maxNumber: maxNumber) { (result) -> Void in
        self.nearbyStops = result!
        self.test()
    }
}

func test() {
    let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        }
        for item in self.nearbyStops {
            let items = item.getDepartures()
            print(item.name!)
            for element in items {
                element.timeUtilDeparture()
                print("    " + element.name + " - " + element.direction)
                print("          \(element.times)")
                print(element.timeUntilDepartureList)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Stop: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

var departures = [Departure]()
var busses = [Bus]()

init(name: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, stopID: Int64, distance: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.stopID = stopID
    self.distance = distance
    super.init()
    loadDepartures() { (result) -> Void in
        self.sanitizeBusDepartures( { (result) -> Void in
            // THE CURRENT OBJECT IS LOADED WITH DATA
        })
    }
}

/**
    Loads the departures for the current stop.
*/
private func loadDepartures(completion: ((result: Bool) -> Void)!) {
    let date = NSDate()
    let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calender.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: date)
    let currentHour = components.hour
    let currentMinute = components.minute
    let currentDay = components.day
    let currentMonth = components.month
    let currentYear = components.year

    let currentDate = "\(currentDay).\(currentMonth).\(currentYear)"
    let currentTime = "\(currentHour):\(currentMinute)"

    let specificURL = "URL"

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: specificURL)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url)
    { (data, resonse, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            let dataReturned = JSON(data: data!)

            let departures = dataReturned["DepartureBoard"]["Departure"]
            for (_, value):(String, JSON) in departures {
                let busName = value["name"].stringValue
                let stop = value["stop"].stringValue
                let time = value["time"].stringValue
                let delay = value["messages"].intValue
                let date = value["date"].stringValue
                let finalStop = value["finalStop"].stringValue
                let direction = value["direction"].stringValue
                let journeyDetailUrl = value["JourneyDetailRef"]["ref"].stringValue

                self.departures.append(
                    Departure(name: busName,
                        stop: stop,
                        time: time,
                        delay: delay,
                        date: date,
                        finalStop: finalStop,
                        direction: direction,
                        journeyDetailLink: journeyDetailUrl))
            }
        }

        completion(result: true)
    }

    task.resume()
}

private func sanitizeBusDepartures(completion: ((result: Bool) -> Void)!) {
        var tempList = [Bus]()

        for item in departures {
            tempList.append(Bus(name: item.name!, direction: item.direction!, times: item.time!))
        }

        for item in tempList {
            if busses.contains(item) {
                let indexOfElement = busses.indexOf(item)
                busses[indexOfElement!].times += item.times
            } else {
                busses.append(item)
            }

        }

        completion(result: true)
    }
```

As you can see in the above every Bus object loads it's own data from it's own URL, so in my ViewController I want to be sure that every Stop object is loaded with data.

Comment: Please add your code here. I'll help you! :)

Comment: I'll edit my post and paste the code, give me a moment ;o)

Comment: What your saying is, the object is nil until that completion block is called (on the line // THE CURRENT OBJECT IS LOADED WITH DATA)?

Comment: When the completion is done, I know that the array of Busses is filled. I get such a completion in every Object, and in my ViewController I want to get the Stop objects when their Bus objects is present. If I just run it right away it'll just contain one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a bad idea to make assumptions about time when you work with async requests, yes, `dispatch_groups` would work, but I propose a simpler solution, delegates, create a protocol `StopDelegate` or some name that makes sense to you, every `Stop` object can have a `stopDelegate` variable:

```
protocol StopDelegate: class {
   func stopDidFetchDepartures(stop: Stop)
}

class Stop: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
   weak var stopDelegate: StopDelegate?
   ...
}
```

The `Stop` object informs it's delegate when the departures and busses information is ready:

```
loadDepartures() { (result) -> Void in
    self.sanitizeBusDepartures( { (result) -> Void in
        // THE CURRENT OBJECT IS LOADED WITH DATA
        self.stopDelegate. stopDidFetchDepartures(self)
    })
}
```

When you assign the `nearbyStops` variable of the `LoadingViewController` you can assign the controller as the delegate of every `stop` object and implement the delegate, you also need a counter of the stops that already finished loading:

```
var stopDeparturesFetchedCount = 0

func stopDidFetchDepartures(stop: Stop) {
   stopDeparturesFetchedCount += 1
   if stopDeparturesFetchedCount >= nearbyStops.count {
      print("All stops finished loading")
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of using a delegate, so every time an object is done, my ViewController know, and can compare to the amount of objects in the list. I just had some weird thought about that being bad practice, if a model refers to a ViewController.

Comment: So I can actually just run the method to show the data instead of the print above?

Comment: Strictly speaking yes it is a bad practice for a model to refer to a controller, but your model is already doing work that does not correspond to a model, it is making requests to fetch data and processing that data, that work is more appropriate for some service or controller, so the ideal solution would be to decouple your classes so that the request and processing is made by a controller lets say. In any case I think that the delegate pattern is the way to go, if the fetch is done by a controller then you don't have to refer to a controller from a model

Comment: So it would actually be ideal if I moved the fetching to my ViewController or a helper class. And a function in the helper take the array of stops, and populate it all?

Comment: That's right, I wouldn't use the ViewController, I would use a Helper class, something like `StopsFetcher` or `StopsManager` this class would perform the stops request and every departures request and process the data and the ViewController would use only one method of that class that asynchronously return the information of all the stops and all departures.

Comment: So I just call the function from the Helper in the ViewController, but how do I know when it's done? Just a simple completionblock?

Comment: Yes a completion block, the problem of knowing when all the requests are completed is solved, so the helper class will call that completion block to inform the ViewController when the info is ready

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115047/discussion-between-recusiwe-and-juanjo).

Answer (score 0):

Fire a notification when all the elements are added like:

```
self.departures.append(
                    Departure(name: busName,
                        stop: stop,
                        time: time,
                        delay: delay,
                        date: date,
                        finalStop: finalStop,
                        direction: direction,
                        journeyDetailLink: journeyDetailUrl))
            }
        }

        completion(result: true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Completed", object: nil)
    }

    task.resume()
}

private func sanitizeBusDepartures(completion: ((result: Bool) -> Void)!) {
        var tempList = [Bus]()

        for item in departures {
            tempList.append(Bus(name: item.name!, direction: item.direction!, times: item.time!))
        }

        for item in tempList {
            if busses.contains(item) {
                let indexOfElement = busses.indexOf(item)
                busses[indexOfElement!].times += item.times
            } else {
                busses.append(item)
            }

        }

        completion(result: true)

    }
```

And then receive it in `test()`:

```
func test(notification: NSNotification){
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.test(_:)), name: "Completed", object: nil)
//Your code..
}
```

Then remove observer:

```
deinit{
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: That's not really the problem. How can I, in my ViewController, know when all the objects are loaded with data? All the stops.

Comment: You want to know when the array `nearbyStops` is filled completely right?

Comment: Sort of, I want to now when `nearbyStops` `Bus` objects are filled completely.

Comment: Can you please mark in the code where you need to know that process is done?

Comment: In my `test()` function in my ViewController, right now I wait for 2 seconds, but obviously that's not the way to go.

Comment: Yes that's what I asked. You want to execute `tests()` when the array `nearbyStops` is completely filled correct?

Comment: Yea, but not just when the array is filled, I want the array Busses inside every Stop to be filled as well. My Stop objects know when the array is filled, but my ViewController doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115041/discussion-between-dershowitz123-and-recusiwe).

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you should not violate MVC while using the same.You should adopt MVVM pattern instead of MVC for that.
Below is exhaustive tutorial to incorporate the same in your ios app.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/74106/mvvm-tutorial-with-reactivecocoa-part-1